# Suppose $z_1 = r_1 (\cos θ_1 + i \sin θ_1)$ and $z_2 = r_2 (\cos θ_2 + i \sin θ_2).$ If $z_1 = z_2$, then how are $r_1$ and $r_2$ related? ....

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z_1 = r_1 (\cos θ_1 + i \sin θ_1)$ and $z_2 = r_2 (\cos θ_2 + i \sin θ_2)$. If $z_1 = z_2$, then how are $r_1$ and $r_2$ related? How are $θ_1$ and $θ_2$ related?

**My attempt**

Let $z_1$,$z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z_1=z_2$ then $z_1-z_2=0$.
This implies

$(r_1\cos\theta_1-r_2\cos\theta_2)+(r_2\sin\theta_2-r_1\sin\theta_1)=0$

Here, i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: $|z_1|=|z_2|$ , i.e.$r_1=r_2$.Your thoughts?

Comment: I assume, you want $r_k\ge 0$ and $\theta_k\in [0,2\pi)$ or something like that?

Comment: Yes @HagenvonEitzen thanks for answer.

Comment: Are $r_1, r_2$ real?

Comment: Are $r_k \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_1 = z_2$, then $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the same complex number. If $r_1$ is the module of $z_1$ and $r_2$ is the module of $z_2$ both are the same number, so $r_1 = r_2$. $\theta_1$ is the argument of $z_1$ and $\theta_2$ is the argument of $z_2$. Both are the argument of the same number, but $cos(\theta + 2n\pi) = cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta + 2n\pi) = sin(\theta)$. We can only say that there exist some $n \in Z$ such that $\theta_1 = \theta_2 + 2n\pi$.

$$ z_1 = z_2 \Rightarrow r_1 = r_2 \quad \theta_1 = \theta_2 + 2n \pi $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
r_1 (\cos \theta_1 + i\sin \theta_1 ) &= r_2 (\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2)\\
r_1e^{i\theta_1} &= r_2e^{i\theta_2}\\
r_1 &= r_2e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}\\
\left|r_1\right| &= \left|r_2e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}\right|\\
&=\left|r_2\right|\cdot\left|e^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}\right|\\
&=\left|r_2\right|
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $r_1,r_2$ are non-negative reals and $\theta_1, \theta_2\in \Bbb R,$ we have $$r_1^2=(Re(z_1))^2 +(Im(z_1))^2=(Re(z_2))^2+(Im(z_2))^2=r_2^2,$$ which implies $r_1=r_2$ because $r_1,r_2\in [0,\infty).$

If $z_1=z_2=0$ then $r_1=r_2=0$ and then $\theta_1, \theta$ are not related  because $0=0(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)$ for $all$  $\theta$.

If $r_1=r_2=r\ne 0$ then $$r\cos \theta_1=Re(z_1)=Re(z_2) =r\cos \theta_2)$$ and also $$r\sin \theta_1=Im(z_1)=Im (z_2)=r\sin \theta_2,$$ and since $r\ne 0,$ this implies $$(\cos \theta_1=\cos \theta_2\land \sin \theta_1=\sin \theta_2),$$ which implies $$(\theta_1 -\theta_2)/(2\pi)\in \Bbb Z.$$ E.g. for $z_1=z_2=1 ,$ we have $r=1$ and $1=1(\cos 2\pi n+i\sin 2\pi n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z.$